# Do I have to make a suggestion or can I just end turn?

Tags: cluedo

The rules are not clear. Every turn I can make a suggestion once I am in a room, but do I have to? Can I just end my turn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the rules [here](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/Clue_(2002).pdf)

> As soon as you enter a room, make a suggestion.

It's very common in games rules to use the word 'may' when something is optional.  The rules use the word 'may' in other places.  This would mean that making a suggestion is compulsory on entering a room.

However you may not remain in a room on your next turn. (and thus make another suggestion)

> You may make only one Suggestion after entering a particular room.  To
> make your next Suggestion, you must either enter a different Room or,
> sometime after your next turn remain in a particular Room.

Thats not how I was taught the game as a child and we just stayed in the same room making suggestions!  So I've learnt something new today.

Comment: What if you are very close to make an accusation because only few clues left, do you just start making random suggestions even though you’ve already mentioned it earlier?

Comment: That for you as the player to make a tactical decision on.  I'm just answering the rules question!  as it is not 'may' then you 'must' make a suggestion on entering a room.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is, "*Am I* required *to make a suggestion whenever I enter a room?*", then strictly speaking the answer is yes.  The rules explicitly say "*make a suggestion*".

However (except in the case of the first time in the game that a player enters a room) in practice you can effectively avoid this by simply repeating a suggestion that you or someone else has previously made.

And making it look like a mistake could be more advantageous than giving people the information that you are refraining from making a suggestion.